# MVC Catch validation exception structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I want to create a base controller that catches the NotificationExceptions, puts the exception messages to viewbag and shows it in a partial notification view.
Everything is good but i have a problem. My base controller OnException event is below.

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {

        Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;

        if (exception is NotificationException)
        {

            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                TempData = new TempDataDictionary
                {
                    { "",exception.Message }
                },
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(filterContext.Result)


            };

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
```

i assume that i will have action names different from viewname. when this happens the code above not working, because it searched the view with the name action. I cant know viewname in this event.
how can i handle this situation?

Comment: What view name you want to be searched in this case?

Comment: For example i have a csthml file Person and post action named Save. this codes looks for Save.cshtml view but there is no, i think i should set the view name but cant know which view